# GAE URL Fetch Service for HTTPS

Tags: java, google-app-engine, urlfetch

My app is throwing this error:

```
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
[INFO]  at info.modprobe.browserid.Verifier.verify(Verifier.java:76)
```

And the code causing the error is:

```
        URL verifierURL = new URL(this.url);
        String response = "";
        HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) verifierURL
                .openConnection(); // error here...
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

When trying to do Mozilla Personal Verification using this [library](https://github.com/user454322/browserid-verifier/). I wonder what could be the problem since GAE URL Fetch Service supports HTTPS.

Comment: smells like an import problem, could you please provide the import block for this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) verifierURL.openConnection();
```

instead of

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) verifierURL.openConnection();
```

It will create what it needs underneath, also for HTTPS, but don't force the cast to HttpS, because it uses a class (URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection) taht extends HttpURLConnection but not HttpsURLConnection